# No log for service termination

Tags: logging, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have application service running on windows server 2012 R2.
The service terminated (probably due to an error) but there is no exception/entry in the event viewer.
Where could I find the cause now.
There is no crash report under WER as well.

Any idea?

Comment: Make sure that you are looking in the [right places in the Event Viewer](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/event-viewer-troubleshoot-windows-services/)...

Comment: Yes, I looked at the correct locations in the event viewer.